# Как в Android Studio тестировать участок кода на время прохождения?

Tags: java, android, тестирование

Как в Android Studio тестировать определенный участок кода на время прохождения?

Всё что мне необходимо — это получить данные и показать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Лучше позже чем никогда. Вопрос довольно простой на первый взгляд, и решить его можно разными способами. После прочтения ряда статей, тестов с разных источников, в основном официальных, я решил эту проблему следующим путем:

Покрывал я участки кода [JUnitPerf](http://clarkware.com/software/JUnitPerf.html) у него есть парочка оболочек на время прохождения, в случае отклонение, выводим что необходимо. И это, то что я искал.

Но вопрос был сформулирован по другому, для этого я эмулировал несколько ситуаций и сделал свой тест: вначале я использовал разные БД(было интересно), позже я упростил и использовал различные интерфейсы коллекций и записывал и удалял небольшое кол-во записей, а точней 100.000, как оказалось позже это очень удачное число, но не суть. Я уже знал, что в корне необходимо использовать два нативных метода системы, но мы вернемся немного назад, почему так измерять нельзя?:

```
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date())
```

Я думаю многие знают или догадываются, но вкратце - много здесь ненужных действий начиная стилей даты, создание объекта, потом нам необходимо как-то измерять точку входа и выхода - autoboxing etc, всё это создаст огромную погрешность, и в итоге сильный разброс при замере одной и той же операции. Но если даже всё убрать и сделать так:

```
Date date = new Date();
```

Даже так плохо, мы тратим время на создание объекта класса, и его внутреннюю реализацию, смотрим внутрь и видим

```
public Date() {
    this(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

Нас это больше чем устраивает, чтоб не плодить экземпляры класса. Это и есть один из методов, второй рядышком давайте их запишем вместе, через вызов, чтоб было удобней читать:

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
System.nanoTime();
```

Возвращает long, второй более точный(подробный), в наносекундах.
Читаем оф документацию и видим в nanoTime():

> This timestamp should only be used to measure a duration by comparing
>   it against another timestamp on the same device.

Есть нюансы, но суть в оф документации там всё очевидно: [nanoTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) и рядом  [currentTimeMillis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis())

После этого можно окончить, но вернемся к тесту. Много информации о том, что погрешность может исчисляться 10-15мс в зависимости от ситуаций(напомню между двумя этими подходами), я хотел бы это опровергнуть, но.... я сделал огромное кол-во пусков теста с различными параметрами с разными устройствами, я учитывал множество факторов, значения записывал только после выделения памяти, учитывал номер записи у меня был алгоритм подсчета среднего значения и ещё оооочень большое кол-во нюансов, и самый сильный разброс был таков:

```
System.nanoTime(); //374-412мс
System.currentTimeMillis(); //386-439мс
```

Это индивидуальный случай, и скорей всего ошибки в замерах, но это факт. Возможно если увеличить кол-во записей в N кол-во всё и свелось бы к min, но я написал, что это был самый сильный разброс. В среднем как раз и было 10-15мс, но иногда иногда как в примере выше был другой рез-т.

В итоге ответ:

```
   long startTime = System.nanoTime();
   // ... the code being measured ...
   long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

Самый точный способ замера участка кода, на одном устр-ве из тех которые я нашел.

Answer (score 3):

Например можно сделать вывод в лог текущего времени в начале и в конце тестируемого кода и посмотреть на разницу:

```
Log.d("Log", DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
```

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ.