# Насколько быстрый onClickLstener?

Tags: android

Как посчитать количество миллисекунд от момента нажатия на экран до начала работы метода onClick?

```
        button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
.....
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511874/191270

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать посчитать количество миллисекунд от момента нажатия на кнопку до начала работы метода onClick таким образом:

```
long start, timeConsumedMillis;
button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
button1.setOnTouchListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
      start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    timeConsumedMillis = timeConsumedMillis - System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Если же нужно считать время от момента нажатия на любое место на экране, то нужно назначить слушателя касания для всего `Layout`-а:

```
pl = (View) findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
pl.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Comment: Интересно, как расчитать от момента касания пальца экрана до onTouch события. в GameDev тоже используется OnTouchListener?

Comment: Во-первых, это будет ничтожно малое время, а во-вторых, это и нереально сделать - так как для ОС Android касание пальцем экрана == вызов метода onTouch. Возможно, это можно сделать на более низком уровне, но, я думаю, игра не стоит свеч.

Comment: можно если поставить авто нажатие, и замерить время до функции(метода вызова) только используйте nanotime, я писал про замеры здесь, но уверен что очень актуально до сих пор http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511874/191270

Answer (score 4):

А что вы называете моментом нажатия на экран? В нажатии есть как минимум 2 события: прикосновение пальца и отпускание. onClick генерируется при отпускании и [судя по коду](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java) помещается в конец очереди сообщений основного потока, так что как быстро оно будут вызвано зависит от загруженности этой очереди.

Если вам нужно мгновенное реагирование на события от нажатий, то лучше подписываться на onTouch.

Comment: Интересно, как расчитать от момента касания пальца экрана до onTouch события. в GameDev тоже используется OnTouchListener?

Comment: ну быстрее onTouch будет только чтонить нативное на C++ типа [такого](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24054513/2893248). В гейм деве часто как раз используют нативные штуки и почти не привлекают Java код.

Comment: как раз работаю с NDK, все сенсоры залиты в java оболочку и нет смысла их выдергивать, даже если каким-то боком вы обойдете JNI, я сомневаюсь в эффективности способа в сторону perfomance. Ибо native activity также перекидывает мост в SENSOR, и выдергивает из java. Простыми словами будет даже медленней работать.